# Display ListView dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, webforms

Is there a way to display ListView without knowing field names? In code behind I am passing data to ListView but don't know how to display it because I am planning to use this template for all my tables.

In template something like

```
<tr>
    foreach( Key in ListView.Keys )
    {
        <th>Key</th>
    }
</tr>
foreach( Row in LisView.Rows )
{
    <tr>
        foreach ( Column in Row )
            <td>Column</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Example of Output:

```
----------------------------
| id  | name    | surname  |
----------------------------
| 1   | John    | Doe      |
| 2   | Jack    | Jones    |
| 3   | Mary    | Williams |
| 4   | Sue     | Smith    |
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use a `GridView` with AutoGenerated columns set to true will solve this problem also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better way:

Html

```
<asp:Table ID="testTable" runat="server" />
```

Code

```
            TableRow tHeaderRow = new TableHeaderRow();

            tHeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

            testTable.Rows.Add(tHeaderRow);

            foreach (DataColumn column in all("Users").Columns)
            {
                TableHeaderCell tHeaderCell = new TableHeaderCell();
                tHeaderCell.Text = column.ColumnName;
                tHeaderRow.Cells.Add(tHeaderCell);
            }

            foreach( DataRow row in all("Users").Rows)
            {
                TableRow tRow = new TableRow();

                testTable.Rows.Add(tRow);

                foreach (DataColumn column in all("Users").Columns)
                {
                    TableCell tCell = new TableCell();
                    tCell.Text = row[column.ColumnName].ToString();
                    tRow.Cells.Add(tCell);
                }
            }
```

my `all("Users")` function returns `DataTable`

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

HTML

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID = "PlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
```

Namespaces

```
using System.Data;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
```

Code

```
    //Populating a DataTable from database.
    DataTable dt = this.GetData();

    //Building an HTML string.
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

    //Table start.
    html.Append("<table border = '1'>");

    //Building the Header row.
    html.Append("<tr>");
    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
    {
        html.Append("<th>");
        html.Append(column.ColumnName);
        html.Append("</th>");
    }
    html.Append("</tr>");

    //Building the Data rows.
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        html.Append("<tr>");
        foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
        {
            html.Append("<td>");
           html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
            html.Append("</td>");
        }
        html.Append("</tr>");
    }

    //Table end.
    html.Append("</table>");

    //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
```